# How to use IValueConverter implementation from another file?

Tags: c#, binding, ivalueconverter

I have `IValueConverter` implementation - `IconExtractor`. I use it this way:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource iconExtractor},
                        ConverterParameter=c:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll|72}"/>
```

But for it to work, the `IconExtractor` must reside in the code-behind-file of the XAML, e.g: my main window is `MainWindow.xaml`, so the class `IconExtractor` must be in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. I cannot place it elsewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IValueConverter` class can be anywhere you want, including in another assembly. Based on your use, you need to have a resource somewhere accessible from your `MainWindow` class. An easy way is to have it in your window resources.

```
<MainWindow.Resources>
    <my:IconExtractor x:Key="iconExtractor"/>
</MainWindow.Resources>
```

You can also use the resources in `App.xaml`, since its resources are accessible from all XAML based classes in your project. Using `App.xaml` appeals to me since you can avoid duplicating effort if more than one window in your project will use `IconExtractor`.

Comment: It keeps saying `The type 'my:IconExtractor' was not found...` I placed it in: `<Window.Resources><my:IconExtractor my:Key="theIconExtractor"/>...</Window.Resources>` and the class is `public class IconExtractor : IValueConverter{...}`. It's in the same namespace as the main window. What am I missing ? does the `my` namespace should be declared in some specific name ?

Comment: It does work if I place the class code (`c#` code) in the main window's cs file.  How come?

Comment: Don't put it in the main window's code behind file. `my` was just a sample namespace alias in XAML that is commonly used. If `IconExtractor` is in namespace `Tal.Stuff`, in the `<Window>` tag in your XAML file you would have `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Tal.Stuff"`. That allows you to use classes directly from `Tal.Stuff` using `my` in XAML, as I did above.